# How to make this input text field responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design

Open in full window and resize the window the input field is not responsive so the button moves below the input which is not what i want.

```css
.coupon {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 22px;
}
.coupon-btn {
  background: #21b85b;
  border: 0;
  padding: 7px 20px 7px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
    font-size:0.875;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="coupon input-res">
<button class="coupon-btn">Apply</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```css
.flex-col {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}

.coupon {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 30px;
}

.coupon-btn {
  background: #21b85b;
  border: 0;
  padding: 7px 20px 7px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 0.875;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-col">
  <input type="text" class="coupon input-res">
  <button class="coupon-btn">Apply</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try with `width: calc(100% - 86px);`.

```css
.coupon {
  width: calc(100% - 86px);
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 22px;
}
.coupon-btn {
  background: #21b85b;
  border: 0;
  padding: 7px 20px 7px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
    font-size:0.875;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="coupon input-res">
<button class="coupon-btn">Apply</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding some mediaqueries

```
 @media(max-width: 37em){
  .coupon{width: 50%;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Must Learn @media contents https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

otherwise, use Bootstrap https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/

The easy way is to use bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 80% 20%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.coupon {
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

.coupon-btn {
  background: #21b85b;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
    font-size:0.875;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="coupon input-res">
  <button class="coupon-btn">Apply</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Wrap the elements into a `.container` and use `display: grid`

You can give column width to on the container as you want it to be! I have used percentage, instead you can use pixel.

For reference go through this link https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Hope it'll solve your problem